# Latex header spanning full page width

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am preparing a document for bookbinding. I want to add a colored header which spans the whole width of the page so that I can trim the book later. I currently found an option which achieves almost what I want, but not quite. I can extend the header vertically as much as I wish via `vspace{}`, but horizontally, there is always a small white gap:

[image]

How can I extend it to the edge of the page? Here is my MWE. I saw some suggestions to load geometry before fancyhdr but I already do this.

```
\documentclass [a5paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Define the header style
\definecolor{strava}{HTML}{FC4C02}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear existing headers and footers
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \colorbox{strava}{%
        \parbox{148mm}{%
            \vspace{2mm}
            \hspace{3mm}
            \vspace{2mm}
            \textcolor{white}{\bfseries\Large Header}
        }%
    }%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove the horizontal rule below the header

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
%\addtolength{\headheight}{-1cm}
\cfoot{Page \thepage}
text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Since you're using `\fancyhead[L]`, the header doesn't start at the left paper border but at the inner border of the left margin. You could add negative `hspace` in front of the `parbox` which should work but may result in a warning. One other option is to use `shipout` to place the box in the `foreground` of the page, like an extra layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine `fancyhdr` with `clrstrip` nested in a `minipage` (the `minipage` is necessary for correct alignment).

To still position things were `fancyhdr` would position them (left, centre, right) we can use `\fancycenter`.

```
\documentclass [a5paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in,includeheadfoot,headheight=14.4pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{clrstrip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\definecolor{strava}{HTML}{FC4C02}

\usepackage{duckuments}% dummy contents

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]
  {%
    \begin{minipage}[b][0pt]{\textwidth}
      \leavevmode
      \begin{colorstrip}{strava}[outer=0cm,inner top=2cm]
        \color{white}\bfseries\Large
        \fancycenter{Header}{}{}%
      \end{colorstrip}%
    \end{minipage}%
  }
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Just not sure how I can adjust the size of the box vertically right now...

Comment: @KosioVarbenov change the `headheight`, if you want a white strip above the red/strava one reduce the `inner top=2cm` to something smaller (`inner top=0pt` would mean tight around the bounding box of the text).